# WebRTC ICE Candidate could not be added error

Tags: websocket, webrtc, ice-protocol

I am getting this error when I addICECandidate

```
var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({sdpMLineIndex:message.label,
                            candidate:message.candidate});
                        pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);

My candidate is forming correctly still I am getting this error.
```

Error is:
Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added.

My issue is while creating offer pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, onSignalingError,   sdpConstraints); here nothing happens neither setLocalAndSendMessage is called neither onSignalingError thats why later on candidate could not be added.

Comment: Has the peerconnection set the remote SDP yet? You cannot add remote Ice candidates until you have set the remote SDP.

Comment: what do you mean formed? LOCAL ice candidates are gathered and added automatically. The `addIceCandidate` function is to add REMOTE ice candidates AFTER you set the remote SDP from the other party.

Comment: I have set the remote SDP as well as parsed it to extract the message label and message candidates, but when I addIceCandidate It throws an error.

Comment: Don't do that. Candidates that are included in the SDP are added automatically. You are trying to add duplicate candidates if you are parsing them out and re-adding them after setting the remote SDP.

Comment: My issue is while creating offer  pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, onSignalingError,       sdpConstraints);  here nothing happens neither setLocalAndSendMessage is called neither onSignalingError

Comment: I am guessing your peerconnection object is not create properly or your callbacks are incorrect. Without the context of the code I cannot be sure what the issue is.